# Switch Statement Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a bar code application in which I am selecting a prefix before that bar code and scanning the according to that code which is being scanned.

I have set up a switch statement but somehow it's not going into the else part/default part.

My code is here:

```
Switch(PrefixSelected.Selected.Title,
    // if the user has selected (1S) and if he tries to scan a serial code, or any other code which does not match, it will show a popup, Not a 1S  Code

    "1S", Set(_NotISCode, !(PrefixSelected.Selected.Title = Left(BarcodeScanner2_5.Value,2))),
    
    // if the user has selected (S) and if he tries to scan a serial code, or any other code which does not match, it will show a popup, Not a S  Code enter code here
enter code here

    "S", Set(_NotSerialCode, !(PrefixSelected.Selected.Title = Left(BarcodeScanner2_5.Value,1))),

    // Is it a duplicate?
    If(!IsEmpty(Filter('Barcodes - Test',  BarcodeScanner2_5.Value = Title)),
        Set(_DuplicateScan, true), // Duplicate Popup
        
        // ELSE - Patch Command
        UpdateContext({patchedRecord:
            Patch('Barcodes - Test',    
                Defaults('Barcodes - Test'),
                {
                    SerialCode:Right(BarcodeScanner2_5.Value,8),
                    Title:BarcodeScanner2_5.Value,
                    'Batch No': BatchSelection.Selected.Title,
                    ReceiveCheck: ToggleIssue.Value,
                    UserName:MyUser, 
                    ReceivedSatus: "Yet To Receive",
                    When:Today() + Time(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()),Second(Now()))    
                },
                If(PrefixSelected.Selected.Title="1S",
                    {'Product Code': Mid(BarcodeScanner2_5.Value,3,10)},
                    {}
                )
        )
        }        
    )
 )
)
```

The code is showing the Above two Popups if I scan the wrong codes,
but if I scan the correct codes it's not patching the values.

Where I am wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you,

Put your **If** statement inside a button (e.g. FunctionButton) and then in your Default option from the **Switch** statement, do a Select(FunctionButton).

```
Switch(PrefixSelected.Selected.Title,
    // if the user has selected (1S) and if he tries to scan a serial code, or any other code which does not match, it will show a popup, Not a 1S  Code

    "1S", Set(_NotISCode, !(PrefixSelected.Selected.Title = Left(BarcodeScanner2_5.Value,2))),
    
    // if the user has selected (S) and if he tries to scan a serial code, or any other code which does not match, it will show a popup, Not a S  Code enter code here

    "S", Set(_NotSerialCode, !(PrefixSelected.Selected.Title = Left(BarcodeScanner2_5.Value,1))),
    Select(FunctionButton)
)
```

OnSelect of the **FunctionButton**

```
// Is it a duplicate?
    If(!IsEmpty(Filter('Barcodes - Test',  BarcodeScanner2_5.Value = Title)),
        Set(_DuplicateScan, true), // Duplicate Popup
        
        // ELSE - Patch Command
        UpdateContext({patchedRecord:
            Patch('Barcodes - Test',    
                Defaults('Barcodes - Test'),
                {
                    SerialCode:Right(BarcodeScanner2_5.Value,8),
                    Title:BarcodeScanner2_5.Value,
                    'Batch No': BatchSelection.Selected.Title,
                    ReceiveCheck: ToggleIssue.Value,
                    UserName:MyUser, 
                    ReceivedSatus: "Yet To Receive",
                    When:Today() + Time(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()),Second(Now()))    
                },
                If(PrefixSelected.Selected.Title="1S",
                    {'Product Code': Mid(BarcodeScanner2_5.Value,3,10)},
                    {}
                )
        )
        }        
    )
 )
```

Comment: Hello, Murilo I have to use this if statement for scanning a bar code, do I have to use 2 buttons?

Comment: Hello :) you might have to have 2 buttons, but 1 of them, the FunctionButton is not visible and just used by the switch statement as a "call"

Comment: Oh cool, I will apply this and check it out.